# 2 разных window.onload

Tags: javascript

Интересует собственно способ, как вызвать 2 разных window.onload function() возможно ли, чтобы один не перекрывал другой?

```
window.onload = function() {
    код
};

window.onload = function() { //2ой онлоад
    код 
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовать [DOM2](https://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events).

```
window.addEventListener('load',function()
{
    console.log('Я первый обработчик.');
});

window.addEventListener('load',function()
{
    console.log('Я второй обработчик.');
});
```

Comment: а по подробнее можно , сейчас вставлю код в вопрос , могли бы написать пример

Comment: точнее , как мне сделать чтобы их было 2?
использовать и windows.onload и window.addEventListener или возможно addEventListener несколько раз использовать присвоив разные имена

Comment: @S1lllver Ссылку для подробного изучения вопроса привёл в ответе. window.addEventListener можно регистрировать и удалять сколько угодно, а window.onload может быть только один.

Comment: спасибо большое , поправьте если ошибаюсь , мне нужно загружать контейнер номер 1 первым , а после его загрузки , загружать контейнер номер 2 , я думаю эта функция мне подойдет